# Where did the lib project go for google play services?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob, google-play-services

I am trying to use the google play services library to use admob in my game. However, things have changed since last time I did this. It appears with the new update (rev 39) there is no lib project in the google play services folder. How can I add google play services to my libgdx game now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you're using gradle for building your libgdx project. You can easily integrate `AdMob` Ad in your App using gradle.

Keep this dependency in android module build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.1'
}
```

Activity entry in AndoirdManifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
           android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

And the Refresh all gradle projects.

On Mac by default all gms files are inside this folder :

```
/Users/User_Name/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms
```

On Windows :

```
Android_SDK_PATH/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms
```

Comment: I did this and the libraries are now showing up under gradle dependencies however in my Android Launcher code it cannot find the libraries. Any suggestions?

Comment: Clean and rebuild your project, Is there any errors on gradle console ?

Comment: You may face some issue if you're using eclipse otherwise on Android Studio/IntelliJ IDEA it's working fine.

Comment: This seems like it would work, but not for me. I ended up just downloading an old google play services library and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In your Android SDK install location, check out the `/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/` folder for aars of the Google Play Services libraries.